# What is the best way to handle ValueError in python?

Tags: python-3.x, exception

I wanna to check type error in my python app.
Is it a correct way to catch `ValueError` in the following way?

```
async def find_video_by_id(request):
    try:
        id = int(request.query['id'])
        ...
    except ValueError:
        exception_message = "Incorrect type of video id was specified."
        logger.exception(exception_message)
        raven_client.captureException(exception_message)
        raise ValueError(exception_message)
    except Exception as ex:
        logger.exception("find_video_by_id")
        raven_client.captureException()
        raise ex
```

Comment: Sorry but just to understand, why do you raise the exception when you are in the exception ? I tried it on a smaller code and I have an issue when I do it that way.

Answer (score 0):

if you want to have custom and standard Exceptions, you can do as follow:

```
# Custom Exception
class MyError(Exception):
    pass

try:
    id = int(request.query['id']) #raise ValueError automatically if string cannot be parsed
    if id == 'foo': # just to show how to raise a custom Exception
        raise MyError
    else:
        bar()
except ValueError:
     exception_message = "Incorrect type of video id was specified."
     logger.exception(exception_message)
     raven_client.captureException(exception_message)
except MyError:
     exception_message = "Incorrect stuff."
     logger.exception(exception_message)
     raven_client.captureException(exception_message)
```